# Bitwise addition works on Java but fails on Ruby

Tags: java, ruby, algorithm, bit-manipulation

I was reading through the questions on LeetCode and came across with this one:

*"Calculate the sum of two integers a and b, but you are not allowed to use the operator + and -"*

Which is a common question on the web.

Java solution for this question is:

```
public int getSum(int a, int b) {
   while(b!=0){
       int c = a&b;
       a=a^b;
       b=c<<1;
   } 
   return a;
}
```

Which works fine. But the same code in Ruby:

```
def get_sum(a, b)
    while b != 0 do
       c = a & b;
       a = a ^ b;
       b = c << 1;
   end
   return a;
end
```

doesn't work. Actually, it works if both 'a' and 'b' are positive numbers but fails if either 'a' or 'b' is a negative number. I suspect the problem is related with shifting the carrier but isn't it the same in Java too? Do you guys have any idea what is different in Ruby.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359807/signed-and-unsigned-integers-in-ruby)

Comment: Just as side note: why your expectation? The fact that you can write down the same program in two languages absolutely does not mean that each element and type have the absolute same **meaning** in both languages. I would even say that "everything is absolutely the same" would be a rather exceptional situation.

Answer (score 1):

In Java an Integer can be left shifted a fixed number of times before it becomes zero. This number of times is the size or bit count of the integer value (for int it's 32 bits).

That's how your loop breaks in Java as `b` becomes zero.

However in Ruby there's no limit to how many times a number can be left shifted before it becomes zero as there's no fixed bit count for a number in ruby.

That's why `b` grows large (may be till we run out of memory).

That is it shouldn't work even with positive numbers and go in an infinite loop.

To break this infinite loop you can limit the precision of the number by taking AND of every result with a fixed precision.

```
precision = 0xFFFF;
b = (c << 1) & precision;
```

In case of negative numbers there's one more bottle neck.

Since `FixNum` doesn't have a fixed size it actually assumes a negative number after bitwise operation to be a positive number so even if 1111 in 2's complement is -1 ruby takes it for a positive value 15.